# nightmare.js не хочет кликать на ссылке котрая вызывет js code

Tags: javascript, nightmare.js

Работаю над созданием парсера определенной формы на nightmare.js
вот код для нажатия на ссылку:

```
.wait(3000)
.click('a#rptrHospital_rptrHospital_btnHospital_0.rptrLink2')
```

и html узел на котрый направлен данный клик

```
<a id="rptrHospital_rptrHospital_btnHospital_0" class="rptrLink2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('rptrHospital$ctl01$rptrHospital_btnHospital','')">Burnett Medical Center (Grantsburg)</a>
```

и за счёт того что ссылка вызывает выполняющийся js, nigthmare.js не кликает на него, то есть код из ссылки не запускается, а ссылка должна нажиамься чтобы переводит на следуйщую этерацию формы.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - `mouseover` это **не** метод нажатия.

Comment: c .click он тоже не работает 
впрочем я понял как это работает нужно вызвать данный код прямо с nightmsre.js __doPostBack('rptrHospital$ctl01$rptrHospital_btnHospital','') но я не знаю пока как

Comment: А зачем стоит `wait(3000)`? Ждете, когда контент загрузиться?

Comment: да, жду когда он подгрузится, он подгрузился, а кнопка не нажимается (через найтмер) зато в консоле если запустить функцию __doPostBack('rptrHospital$ctl01$rptrHospital_btnHospital','') то мы переходим далее как и нужно, но как эту функцию вызвать в найтмере?

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, на момент нажатия контент еще не загрузился и кнопки просто нету. Как вызвать функцию в nightmare.js я не знаю :)

Comment: спасибо но к моему сожалению это не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем если нужно самым простым образом отработать js скрипт который выполянется в браузере через nightmare.js то тут мне помогло очевидное решение

```
.goto("javascript:__doPostBack('rptrHospital$ctl01$rptrHospital_btnHospital','')")
```

то есть если при выполнении кода страница перезагружается и происходят появления других елементов то это самый просто вариант отработки скрипта
может кому пригодится